# Python: Trying to get the number of logical and physical cores on a 3990X, getting the wrong answer?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the number of physical and logical processors on a given system via Python (v2.7). When I try:

```
import multiprocessing
print multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

I get `64`, which is the number of physical processors available on my 3990X. I thought that function gave the number of logical processors available. How do I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, congratulations on owning a 3990X!

`os.cpu_count()` (or equivalently `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`) is supposed to report the number of logical cores like you stated.

The issue you experienced seems to be a [known bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue30581) in Python that **appears fixed in Python 3.6 and above**. Windows uses a [64-bit bitmask](https://bitsum.com/general/the-64-core-threshold-processor-groups-and-windows/) to keep track of CPU cores, so many applications can run into issues when run on systems with more than 64 logical cores.

I highly recommend to stop using Python 2.7 as it [has reached its end-of-life on January 1st 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2). Python 2 will not be getting any new features or bugfixes, and this is likely one of them.